# GeoLocation + Google Maps API?

Tags: arrays, geolocation, maps, coordinates

i want to use the GeoLocation watchPosition command, to get location data on a phone. With these coords, I want to draw a route in a google map, which updates with every new coord i get into an array with coords.

any advice how i can achieve this?

thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I'm currently working on creating a map page that does something very similar. I fire off watchPosition and then take the coords from the returned results and pass them into the a DirectionsRenderer object that I call the first time. I take this DirectionsRenderer object and store it in an array. Then with every updated coords, I update the Lat/Lng values in the object with the new coords. This seems to work pretty well.

You can see an example of my code [here](http://whmdev.winona.edu/tour/map.htm). The functionality is not perfect, but it works pretty well. See the getUserLocation function for details.